# How to add properties to a spring cloud dataflow application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I am new to spring cloud dataflow. I am writing a 'source' application, but I'm not able to figure out how to add properties to the app. I couldn't find any help in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/).

I followed the [code in the github](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-samples/tree/master/dataflow-template-example) of the sample spring cloud dataflow apps, and tried to implement mine the same way, but was still unable to display the propeties in the dataflow UI.

Comment: link to project : https://github.com/thekindler/spring-cloud-camera.git

Answer (score 0):

The process of adding the application properties into your application is documented in [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-cloud-dataflow-stream-app-whitelisting). In summary, you need to use `spring-boot-configuration-processor` and classify your properties into configuration metadata.

Comment: I have followed the steps as mentioned in the link of your answer, but still i am not able to solve the problem. link to the project :https://github.com/thekindler/spring-cloud-camera.git